# TCL set variable

Tags: tcl

How to set the following variable as shown below in TCL,

**Input:**

```
set top_module "example"

set dummy_variable { $top_module {}}

puts $dummy_variable
```

**Expected Output:**

```
example {}
```

**Actual output, which I am getting**

```
$top_module {}
```

Comment: Refresh yourself on [Rule 6](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10)

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate that variable substitution at the time when the containing variable is set; curly braces *always* inhibit *all* substitutions. Tcl really cares about the details of all this.

Given that you're dealing with the name of something and aren't producing something directly intended for human consumption, you'll probably be happiest with this:

```
set dummy_variable [list $top_module {}]
```

You *could* have used this:

```
set dummy_variable "$top_module {}"
```

But then you would be subject to subtle differences (usually bugs!) when the substituted variable contains a space; the `list` command substitution avoids those.

---

In some cases, you are instead better off doing this:

```
set dummy_variable [list {*}$top_module {}]
```

This is particularly useful when building lists by concatenating values onto them (when you're not able to just use `lappend`).

Comment: Hi Donal, Thank you so much.. This should help me...